# what are the real-world use cases of the LaunchModes in android?

Tags: android, manifest, launchmode

What are Some application examples, or use-cases where (singleInstance, singleTask, singleTop) serves a necessary purpose. i.e. why would one favor one launchMode over the other? so far my experience with them is strictly notes, so it would be helpful to understand where they're used. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand it is known that it means you cannot launch multiple instances of an activity.

In my example, I use `singleInstance` in my main launcher `Activity`, because it has `Fragments`, and it is being launched by notification intent.

If `Activity` was sent to background after user touched "home" button, I don't want it to be launched from background via notification intent, because it will show the last seen fragment. If I set `singleInstance`, it will always launch new instance of activity, and show the main fragment.

In my case I can't use `singleTask` because it holds other activities from my app in the stack, but puts the main activity on top. I don't need that history in the stack.

`singleTop` launches new instance on an activity only if it is not in top of the stack. if it is on top, it launches from background, that's what I don't need in my app.

Hope I was clear :)

Comment: So, singleTask, would be useful for say, google search. if i have 5 apps that can launch the googleSearch activity, they will either launch a new instance of googleSearch(if none exist), or re-launch an instance of googleSearch(if an instance already exist in the backstack)? is that correct to say?

Comment: you mean "5 different apps" or maybe 5 activities in one app? i think it's not working across applications..

Comment: sorry for being ambiguous. basically i meant if any # of activities (regardless of task) tries to launch an app that is singleTask, they will either 1) launch a new instance(if non existent), or 2) they will simple re-launch the instance of the activity(if an instance already exist)? - is that the main premise behind singleTask?

Comment: thats correct about about singleTask and singleTop )) the main point with singleTask is if the app has other activities in stack, they will launch too, but behind the "singleTask" activity. so if a user do backpress , other activities from stack of that app will be shown. i hope its not too confusing )

Comment: it's not too confusing anymore thanks @alinpha. you've really helped me :)